# Need to know when a non-modal window has closed

Tags: c#, wpf, window, modal-dialog

I have opened childwindow from parentWindow (non-modal) - what's the best approach to achieving a 'wait' so that parentWindow will know when childWindow has closed? For a couple of reasons I cannot use showDialog(). I have tried a while loop (testing the childWindow's visibility property) but it just breaks (no exception - but just doesn't open childWindow). Is it a case of multi-threading??

Comment: Why can't you use modal dialogs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what's the best approach to achieving a 'wait' so that parentWindow
>   will know when childWindow has closed?

You could use events so the parent window is notified when the child window closes. For instance, [there is the Closed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx).

```
Window childWindow = new ....
childWindow.Closed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // Put logic here
        // Will be called after the child window is closed
    };
childWindow.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken. Just what I'm looking for. Out of curiosity - is this written using lambda?

Comment: Yes, it's lambda expression. More concise and straightforward than standard event handlers, but in the other hand, you can't easily detach the event with the `-=` operator.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Ties in nicely with the revision I'm doing on lambda then. I'm still quite confused on where the sender and e are coming from but I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: `sender` and `e` are the parameters passed to the event handler. The syntax might look a bit strange with lambda, but it's exactly the same as for normal event handlers. Every event handler has always the same parameters: `sender` that is of type `object`, and `e` that inherits from `EventArgs`. `sender` contains a reference to the instance that raised the event. In your case, it'll be a reference to the `childWindow` object. `e` will contains an `EventArgs` instance, but as this particular event doesn't uses any parameter, it'll be useless for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken, appreciate your feedback mate. I'm ok with understanding the sender and eventArgs when used normally to be honest. I understand Marco's answer perfectly because up until the point I've used lambda it's been clear where the parameters have been coming from, how the type is specified and where they are going, but I'm a bit baffled with regards to visualising where these parameters are coming from and how the lambda knows what type they are (or does lambda!? do I need to cast?). It would make a little bit more sense to me if it was written: (object sender, EventArgs e) => ...

Comment: Actually, `(object sender, EventArgs e) =>` it totally valid ;) It's often not written this way because it's not required: the C# 3.0 (won't work with C# 2.0) compiler (and Visual Studio for Intellisense) is smart enough to do what's called type inference. This allows the compiler to know the type of the parameters depending on the context. You could try to search for type inference in the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-04.aspx

Comment: Thanks a LOT Ken!! It's important for me to know all that, and I had heard of type inference - but putting into context like that has helped a lot more. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
    public ShowChild()
    {
        childWindow child = new childWindow();
        child.Closed += new EventHandler(child_Closed);
        child.Show();
    }

    void child_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Child window closed
    }
```